# Serious bug in Android 4.4.4_r2: Not sending BOOT_COMPLETED Intent

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, boot, bugs

There seems to be a serious bug in Android 4.4.4_r2:

[BOOT_COMPLETED not always sent bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78484)

Causing BOOT_COMPLETED Intent not to be sent. Does anyone know if this issue can be fixed on an Android 4.4.4_r2 device?

Comment: It seems to be more of a programmer problem since very few end users actually can look at that pile of text and understand something.

Comment: Yes it is, but the bug must affect very many end-users with programs not being launched properly on boot. So it seems strange that there are not numerous complaints about this bug.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the BOOT_COMPLETED will be sent when the device is successfully restart and the Keyguard is unlocked the first time. In order to be able to help, post the manufacturer, as well as the ROM name/version. This "bug" does not happen on a Motorola E, Samsung J1 or Sony E3 (devices I have for developing and testing), all runnning 4.4.2

Comment: I agree with Bonatti here. Might be the reason it is not so well-known be the fact that it is a case specific to you? And yeah can be a problem affecting end users however the odds that you'll receive proper information are significantly lower here.

Comment: I have multiple devices running 4.4.4, and not a single of them seems affected. So it might not be that wide-spread as you think. Apart from that, if it's a bug in the OS, plus considering this site is for end-users, we are not the ones to fix it. // @Bonatti strike the "Keyguard unlock" part, that is not involved AFAIK (makes no sense; the event must also fire with the device booting up in your pocket, or the SD card wouldn't be mounted in time and the launcher etc. not started ;)

Comment: OK. I just think it is really strange, since when I browse the source code, the buggy code seems to be present.